# HEX string to UTF-8(UNICODE) string

Tags: c++

I have a HEX string that has Unicode characters in it. and I need to convert that UTF-8(Unicode) and store in a string variable.

I am new in Unicode and I don't have much idea to try anything.

```
std::string HEX_string= "0635 0628 0627 062d 0020 0627 0644 062e 064a 0631";
std:string unicode_string=getUnicodeString(HEX_string);
```

I expect صباح الخير value in unicode_string variable.

Comment: The hex string `0635 0628 ..` is not valid Utf8. The string you did provide as example is encoded in Utf8 as `0xd8 0xb5 0xd8 0xa8 0xd8 0xa7 0xd8 0xad 0x20 0xd8 0xa7 0xd9 0x84 0xd8 0xae 0xd9 0x8a 0xd8 0xb1` ... so I guess your source data are encoded in different encoding?

Comment: Hm, oh, I see, it's probably this U+0635 way of writing it... like here https://www.key-shortcut.com/en/writing-systems/%EF%BA%95%EF%BA%8F%D8%A2-arabic-alphabet ... so you need to also convert those to real Utf8 bytes, I'm not even sure how that `U+` evaluates, as I'm used to work with real binary values, and I never use these above.

Comment: Because those are Utf16, not Utf8 ... so what you are asking for is conversion from Utf16 to Utf8. The conversion from "hexa string" to binary values is simple part, but conversion from Utf16 to Utf8 is lot more difficult task (you should handle invalid unicode characters, and you need conversion tables, which is thousands of characters). If possible, use some well known library, like `iconv` for that, or whatever your platform supports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since that hex string is a bunch of space-separated base-16 encoded Unicode codepoints, it's easy to convert using just standard functions, in particular [std::c32rtomb()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/c32rtomb):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <clocale>
#include <cuchar>
#include <climits>

std::string
getUnicodeString(const std::string &hex)
{
  std::istringstream codepoints{hex};
  std::string cp;
  std::string out;
  std::mbstate_t state;
  char u8[MB_LEN_MAX];

  while (codepoints >> cp) {
    char32_t c = std::stoul(cp, nullptr, 16);
    auto len = std::c32rtomb(u8, c, &state);
    if (len == std::size_t(-1)) {
      std::cerr << "Unable to convert " << cp << " to UTF-8 codepoint!\n";
      std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else if (len > 0)  {
      out.append(u8, len);
    }
  }
  return out;
}

int main() {
  // Make sure that c32rtomb() works with UTF-32 code units
  static_assert(__STDC_UTF_32__);
  // Requires a UTF-8 locale to get a UTF-8 string.
  std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

  std::string HEX_string = "0635 0628 0627 062d 0020 0627 0644 062e 064a 0631";
  std::string unicode_string = getUnicodeString(HEX_string);
  std::cout << unicode_string << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

After compiling it, running it produces:

```
$ echo $LANG
en_US.utf8
$ ./a.out
صباح الخير
```

---

You don't have any codepoints outside the BMP in that sample to be sure if your input is encoded in UTF-16 or UTF-32. The above code assumes UTF-32, but if it's UTF-16 you can change `c32rtomb()` to `c16rtomb()` and `char32_t` to `char16_t` and it'll handle UTF-16 surrogate pairs correctly.

Comment: I didn't know about std::c16rtomb, that's neat. Would it have been the same if there weren't any spaces in the hex string?

Comment: @Nina You'd have to read and convert in blocks of 4 characters. There's a few ways to do that.

Comment: @Shawn Thanks for the answer, while compiling this code on Linux machine and first I am getting "error: cuchar: No such file or directory".

Comment: And @Shawn gcc version installed in my Linux machine is (GCC) 4.4.7. it needs to be updated to compile with c++11 ?

Comment: @RushitSolanki That's a really old version of g++. If it supports C++11 at all it would need to be passed `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11`

Comment: @Shawn I tried to compile using `std=c++11` but it shows **error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"** so I am going to update g++ version.

Comment: @Shawn I update g++ (GCC) (9.1.0) on my centOS 6.x but now getting **error: ‘c32rtomb’ is not a member of ‘std’**.please help me out in this.

Comment: @RushkitSolanki your libc version might also be too old to provide the function.

Comment: @Shawn Thanks, any way to check the version of libc? because code is working on centOS 7.

Comment: @Shawn Hi please help me out of this, now I have ldd (GNU libc) 2.17 version and I can see the result, but sometimes getting **Unable to convert 0635 to UTF-8 codepoint** with same code. anything that I can sort out?

Comment: @Shawn solved now.need to change the variable declaration.
`std::mbstate_t state;` to  `std::mbstate_t state{};` and  `char u8[MB_LEN_MAX];` to `char u8[MB_LEN_MAX]{};`